# How does reverse mobile number carrier look up work?

Tags: mobile, reverse, lookup, phone-number, carrier

For example site,
https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/carrier-lookup

The above website provides reverse mobile number carrier lookup.

Would you anyone explain **how this works** ?
It looks like that there is a tool like "nslookup".

Anyone can say we have DB and serve them via web.
**My question is how the behind process works.**

If it is just crawling, where is the source ?

Answer (score 0):

The [very page you linked](https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/carrier-lookup) asks and answers that question:

> **How does the phone carrier lookup tool work?**
>
> Our software uses two
>   databases: one for landline numbers, with their corresponding data,
>   and one for mobile numbers, with their corresponding data. You can
>   find any number from the United States, United Kingdom, Canada and
>   other countries. When you enter a phone number in the carrier lookup
>   service, our software compares it with the information in our database
>   and extracts information on it instantly.

Now, you might say that only begs the question and then want to know where the data in the database comes from. But at the very least, it answers your suspicion that there's an `nslookup`-like tool for phone numbers. According to the web site, they created the tool, and it looks like the web page is the only way you can access it.

Comment: Thanks Caleb for your answer. My question was not clear enough. My question is how the behind process works.

Comment: I'm curious too...where the database comes from? Do these providers partner with the carriers? There are a lot of providers for reverse lookup.